# How do I dismiss a File Open dialog in an XCTest UI test?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

My Mac app has a File Open dialog which I need to dismiss as part of an XCTest UI test, so that the test can proceed to access parts of the application that are blocked by dialogs. How can I dismiss the dialog in the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have any other dialogs open at the time, and your File Open dialog has a Cancel button, you can make a (perhaps questionable) assumption that the dialog is the first one in the `XCUIApplication().dialogs` query and dismiss it like this:

```
let openDialog = app.dialogs.elementBoundByIndex(0)
openDialog.buttons["Cancel"].click()
```